# How Does Four normal projection of 4D Riemann tensor vanish?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

I am studying numerical relativity from the books of Baumgarte & Shapiro. At the page 39 (eq. 2.86), it is said that $$n^{p}n^{q}n^{r}n^{s}~{}^{(4)}R_{pqrs}$$ vanishes, where $n^a$ is normal vector on given slice, due to symmetry properties of Riemann tensor. Although I know that 
$$
R_{pqrs} = - R_{qprs} \\
R_{pqrs} = - R_{pqsr} \\
R_{pqrs} = R_{rsqp} \\
$$ 
I couldn't understand how the term above vanishes? I would be really grateful for any help.

Comment: It's antisymmetric in the first two indices. The normal vectors are symmetric.

Comment: Assuming the manifold is analytic and torsion free, are you using the exponential mapping where the Riemann tensor is defined at $T(M)_{P}$ on a geodesic, and the normal coordinates are defined at $M_{m}$ along the same geodestic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the tensor given by the multiplication of two normal vectors: $$N^{pq}=n^pn^q=n^qn^p=N^{qp},$$
meaning $N$ is a symmetric tensor.

Now you can rewrite:
$$n^pn^qn^rn^sR_{pqrs}=N^{pq}N^{rs}R_{pqrs}.$$
However, the Riemann tensor is, as you have mentioned, anti-symmetric in the first two (and last two) indices, so in fact you have a full contraction of a symmetric and an anti-symmetric tensor (with respect to either the first or last pair of indices).

As you might recall, the full contraction of a symmetric and an anti-symmetric tensor always vanishes.